# Major FIREFOX Redirect Error Problem (Error Code 11156)

Tags: gmail, facebook, google-spreadsheets, firefox, firefox-extensions

I would appreciate some help please. When I try to log into some website, im being redirected to the members only page (e.g. dashboard, main account, etc) but instead of successfully landing there as I have always done in the past, 100% blank page occurs with nothing, and i mean absolutelly nothing, being shown but complete white screen of firefox page. After the classical (normal) part of starting URL, this URL gets the following addition at the end: .../Error-COL.html?ErrorCode=11156 So the error code is 11156. Here is the list of subjects I have done so far but did NOT help:

- updated firefox to the most recent version
- tried different internet browsers (same problem)
- contacted technical IT customer support and everything fine on their website
- cleaned cookies
- cleaned Flash cookies
- cleaned registry
- made sure there is no proxy involved in firefox's settings
- DOUBLE checked that firewall wouldn't stop anything - i don't have firewall at all
- scanned system for any potential malware/worms with 3 different such programs
- scanned completely with Avast also
- rebooted pc

Answer (score 0):

Their technical support may be wrong IMHO.  It really sounds like something that they updated on their end, but messed up (perhaps their webadmin has a redirect going to a nonexistent page on their end), especially if you are getting the same result on a different browser.

If you have a smartphone available with a 3G/4G connection that's not on your Wifi, try accessing the site using its browser.  If you get the same result, it's not anything to do with your computer or ISP, and IMHO you've eliminated everything possible on your end.